# Blazor individual account fails with "ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'. (Parameter 'value')"

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, .net-core, blazor

I have created Blazor application with VS2019 community wizard. I chose individual account and configured like this:

```
    "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://my-domain-from-azure.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "copy-pasted-guid-from-azure-here",
    "CallbackPath": "https://localhost:44308/signin-oidc/",
    "Domain": "my-domain-from-azure.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_xxxx_signup_signin",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_xxxx_password_reset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_xxxx_edit"
}
```

Next startup looks exactly like from startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

When I try to run the application I get this error message:
[image]

This drives me crazy, I have search SO, tried to remove/add all `/` from `.json` from `.cs` from error handling, still, the error occurs.

Any idea what am I missing, doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing this line `app.UseExceptionHandler("Error");` to this `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` and see if helps.

Comment: Try changing your CallbackPath to just /signin-oidc - i.e. a relative url?

Comment: @MisterMagoo if you can put that as an answer I'm more than happy to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your CallbackPath to just /signin-oidc - i.e. a relative url